# How to set/modify model in controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm doing a basic example for ajax operation in ember 1.7.0, What I did is have a model in route and did a ajax get for raw data.

```
App.IndexRoute=Em.Route.extend({ 
                       model:function(){
                            return Em.$.get('data.json');
                        },
                  }
```

Now in controller I want to modify this for the template, I tried

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init:function(){this._super();
                  var newmodel=this.get('content');
                       ....some modification...
                         this.set('model',newmodel);
                   }
                }
```

but this is not working.

So how basically One modify the model? This should be in setupController or in controller?
if need be how to get and set model in controller? Another confusion is on when to create and when to extend the controller and route?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go for `setupController` hook in your route

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.$.get('data.json');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    //Some modifications
    //..
    //end of modificaitons
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

Comment: you don't need to do `controller.set('model', model);`, that logic already happens in `this._super(controller, model);`, unless of course he's changing model to a new object e.g. `model = {}` instead of just changing a property on model.  Then you'd just wait and call the super at the end with the new model.

Comment: @saygun  Thanks, few doubts : when I did this.set('model',"{'one':'1'}"); in controllers init, and checked the value in setupcontroller by controller.get('model'), and controller.get('content') they are different. ie model is new data that I override in Controller->init, whereas content->original model value returned by Route->model

Comment: @Kingpin2k any help on different behavior of setting/getting model as I wrote in the comment above!

Comment: Would you mind setting up a jsbin showing what your stating?  emberjs.jsbin.com

Answer (score 2):

`extend()` is used to create subclass for any class, for instance, `Ember.ArrayController`. If you want to overwrite the properties (methods) of the existing class you can go with extend.

`create()` is used to create new instance of a class. Refer this http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/

No need to use `setupController` hook of `Route` until you want to set any properties for the controller.

If your Route have model hook and return data, then you can access model directly in your controller by using

```
var model = this.get('model');
```

At the same time you can use setters to update/modify model.

```
this.set('model',newdata);
```

Have a look at simple bin http://jsbin.com/fesux/edit

Kindly have a look at Ember.set and Ember.get also

Comment: I understand the extend and create for class/object, I asked in context of controller & router, What I have seen so far is extend, any use case when we must create? and why extend will not work? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a setupController to handle this

```
App.IndexRoute=Em.Route.extend({ 
  model:function(){
    return Em.$.get('data.json');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('model',model);
  }
}
```

The setupController hook receives the route handler's associated controller as its first argument. In this case, the IndexRoute's setupController receives the application's instance of App.IndexController.

The default setupController hook sets the model property of the associated controller to the route handler's model.

If you want to configure a controller other than the controller associated with the route handler, use the controllerFor method.

More details here:
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/